# Trouble redirecting an error in pipeline using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ls

```
ls -lhR /etc/ | egrep *.conf$ >/home/student/total_size.txt 2>/home/student/error.txt
```

So I used this command to get all .conf files from `/etc/`. I want the output in `total_size.txt` and my errors in `error.txt`. My output looks good, but the errors won't redirect to `error.txt`, they appear in my terminal:

```
ls: cannot open directory '/etc/cups/ssl': Permission denied
```

I don't know what to do; I tried `2>>` instead of `2>` but it won't work either.

Comment: Related, `grep -E` is more portable then `egrep`. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `ls`'s `stderr` still points to the terminal. You need to wrap pipeline in curly braces, and do the redirection outside. E.g:

```
{ ls -lhR /etc/ | egrep *.conf$; } >/home/student/total_size.txt 2>/home/student/error.txt
```

Comment: Since ls's stdout is consumed by egrep, the output redirection can be placed outside the braces too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, should do the trick.

```
ls -lhR /etc/ 2>>/home/student/error.txt | egrep *.conf$ >/home/student/total_size.txt
```

The errors are generated by `ls`, not `egrep`.

Comment: egrep's stderr is still connected to the terminal. what if it fails?

Comment: You should be able to redirect stderr for the egrep again.
    egrep *.conf$ 1>/home/student/total_size.txt 2>/home/student/error.txt